# keep only subset of labels of specific metric in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I wanted to define the scrape config in such a way that for a specific metric it will ingest only a subset of allowed labels, and all of the rest it will throw away.

For example, I have metric A with labels names "test1", "test2", "test3", and metric B with labels names "testa", "testb", "testc".
I want to scrape all of the metric with their labels unless it is metric A which in that case I want to allow only "test1" label of metric A, and the rest will be droppped.
The configuration must work also for cases where another label is added to all metrics, meaning that it should define what we keep instead of what we remove because for any new addition I would have to add a line telling it to drop it, which is not maintainable.

I thought about doing it the following way:

```yaml
relabel_config:
 - source_labels: [A]
   target_label: test1
   action: keepequal
```

is it right that it will affect only the metric A? or will it keep only metric A with label test1?

and if I add another block like that but for `test2`, will it keep both of them or keep none?

Comment: First of all, this being a configuration question is not really on topic for SO. Consider [devops.se] or [su].

Comment: Additionally, in any question, here or on mentioned sites, clarify what do you mean by "labels test1, test2 etc". Are those label names or label values? If former - please clarify what you want for other labels to happen. If latter - what the label name is?

Comment: those are label names.
the other labels can be just dropped.
i will clarify it in the question